# add E-mail validation and character limit using js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, email-validation

So I am new to code java script, learning actually and came across this thing validation. During Form Validation I was able to validate the name, subject and message but didn't understand how I can validate email. Tried doing it and learning but didn't workout well. Also If there is any way of setting minimum word limit instead of minimum character limit in the message box please do help with that too.
Thanks in advance

```js
const name = document.getElementById("fname");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const sub = document.getElementById("subject")

function validate() {
  var isError = false;
  var errMessage = '';
  if (name.value === "" || name.value == null) {
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Please Enter Your Name\n";
  }
  if (sub.value === "" || sub.value == null) {
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Please Enter a Subject\n";
  }
  if (message.value < 40) {
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Your Message Should be Longer";
  }
  if (isError) {
    alert(errMessage);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
.contact-col {
  flex-basis: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-col div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contact-col div .fa {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #f7a335;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.contact-col div p {
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-col div h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.contact-col input,
.contact-col textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f7a335;
  border: 1px solid #f7a335;
  padding: 12px 34px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: solid#f7a335;
  background: #f7a335;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-col">
  <form onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="fname">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail ID">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Subject" id="subject">
    <textarea rows="8" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="red-btn">Send Message</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use `<input type="email">`, you won't need any JavaScript validation as the HTML element has built in validation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus But then It will just take anything which have '@' used in it. I mean like "hi akv@aicon" is also acceped by the form.

Comment: Technically, `"hi akv"@aicon` is a valid email address, though unusual.

Comment: @Ouroborus Well I agree on that partially but it includes space and not .com or .in etc. I mean i hope you get what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i found a help for you.

You can do the matching with RegExp.

Here is my own RegExp:

```
/.*\@.*\.\w{2,3}/g
```

Here is an RegExp i found on internet:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

And this is your code to test:

```js
const name = document.getElementById("fname");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const sub = document.getElementById("subject");
const email = document.getElementById("email")

function validate() {
  var isError = false;
  var errMessage = '';
  if (name.value === "" || name.value == null) {
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Please Enter Your Name\n";
  }
  if (sub.value === "" || sub.value == null) {
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Please Enter a Subject\n";
  }
  if (message.value < 40) {
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Your Message Should be Longer\n";
  }
  console.log(email.value.match(/.*\@.*\.\w{2,3}/g))
  if (email.value === "" || email.value.match(/.*\@.*\.\w{2,3}/g) === null){
    isError = true;
    errMessage += "Please Enter a Valid Email";
  }
  if (isError) {
    alert(errMessage);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
.contact-col {
    flex-basis: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .contact-col div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  
  .contact-col div .fa {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #f7a335;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  
  .contact-col div p {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .contact-col div h5 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  
  .contact-col input,
  .contact-col textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .red-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f7a335;
    border: 1px solid #f7a335;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .red-btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: solid#f7a335;
    background: #f7a335;
    transition: 1s;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="contact-col">
      <form onsubmit="return validate()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="fname">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail ID" id="email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Subject" id="subject">
        <textarea rows="8" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="red-btn">Send Message</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**Notice**:
I change type of input of the email to text to test the validation

Comment: Thank You Very much.

Answer (score 1):

I did for email you can do it for the rest by learning regex: [REGEX tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

**HTML**

```
<div class="contact-col">
  <form name="form1" action="#">
    <input type='text' name='text1' />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.text1)" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contact-col {
  flex-basis: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-col div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contact-col div .fa {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #f7a335;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.contact-col div p {
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-col div h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.contact-col input,
.contact-col textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f7a335;
  border: 1px solid #f7a335;
  padding: 12px 34px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: solid#f7a335;
  background: #f7a335;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

**JS**

```
function ValidateEmail(inputText) {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    alert("Valid email address!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

[my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikshep/dhmLv9n6/21/)

Comment: Could not fig out about the regexp thing before. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

### This is how I do in React js

```
const validateForm = () => {
    let errorFlag = false;
            
    const atposition = email.trim().indexOf('@');
    const dotposition = email.trim().lastIndexOf('.');
    if(atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.trim().length) {
        setemailError('Please enter a valid email Id');
        errorFlag = true;
    }

    if (errorFlag) {
        throw new Error('Form validation failed');
    }
}
```

Specifically, try out the regex part of the above code. Hope it's helpful.